# asp.net requiredfieldvalidator dont work when visible=false

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have some requiredFileldvalidators in my asp.net site that i want to set invisible until needed. But when i set them to visible=false they do not fire. They do work if they are set visible=true.

Is this the correct behavior of this control or is this wrong. I want them invisible due to styling issues when visible.

Comment: What do you mean set them as invisible? a `RequiredFieldValidator` does not display a message unless it needs to - i.e unless you press a button that fires validation and it finds that something is missing

Comment: But if there not visible how do you expect them to be valid?

Comment: The textbox to validate is visible, and i want the fieldvalidator to be invisible until needed. Thats why i have set the property visible=false and the enabled property to true.

Comment: Why set it as invisible? it is already *invisible* unless validation goes wrong (i.e textbox is empty once a button is pressed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting `Visible="false"` in ASP.NET will cause an element to *not* be rendered out to the page. So, it essentially doesn't exist on the client side. They should be invisible by default, and will only be shown if the criteria of requirements is *not* met (or they are otherwise forced by use of `IsValid="false"`).

You can play with the [`Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display.aspx) property to help facilitate layout modes - but I have a feeling this is not entirely related to what you desire to do.

Comment: Good point - there's a walkaround for this issue: set the css `display` property to `none`, and then, once required to be visible again (I see absolutely no point in this, as this control is 'invisible' unless validation goes wrong) by settings `display` to `inline` - both can be done clientside

Comment: Just use Display="dynamic", that keeps it hidden (display: none) until it's triggered, and then it shows it inline.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's because by default the `RequiredFieldValidator` hides itself by setting the `visibility` to `hidden`.

To get it to change `display` to `none` instead (which won't leave an empty gap on the page) remove your `Visible="False"` attribute and add this attribute to the control:

```
Display="Dynamic"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do  this:

```
$("#myField").hide();
```

in jQuery,
or:

```
style="display:none"
```

within the input tag.

Then in will be rendered but just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The Visible property of a asp.net control has nothing to do with styling. Use css for that. Visible controls whether the control is displayed/rendered or not. Maybe your looking for Display="Dynamic"?

Comment: the css for my validatorcontrol has a red border. So that when visible=true on the validator it appears as a red dott.

Answer (score 0):

use validator's "Enabled" property instead, and also set Display property to Dynamic, so it does not take up space while rendering.

That should pretty much do what you need to do.